# using twig in codeigniter project

Tags: php, codeigniter, twig, composer-php

I have a project that I have set up using codeigniter and used composer to install twig.  I am new to codeigniter and composer and am not sure what to do to start using twig in my views.  I have created a file in the views folder called resources/master.html and one called index.html.

In index.html I have just put

```
{% extends "resources/master.html" %}
```

which is simply being rendered on the page as text, seems as if twig is not being loaded.  What do I need to do to get twig to interpret the page?

Comment: I'm no expert, but look into including it in your controller?

Comment: If you like template inheritance, I recommend checking out Laravel. It has it built in their Blade engine. Really quite a good framework.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how to incorporate Composer and Codeigniter.  I suspect you might need to find/write a package that autoloads twig.

I installed a Codeigniter specific package manager,  [sparks](http://getsparks.org/install) and used that to install/integrate Twig via a wrapper package called [twiggy](http://edmundask.github.io/codeigniter-twiggy/). You cd into your Codeigniter project's root directory. Install sparks:

```bsh
$ php -r "$(curl -fsSL http://getsparks.org/go-sparks)"
```

Then you can install the twiggy package. You'll see it in the sparks/ directory where you can see what version was installed:

```bsh
$ php tools/spark install twiggy
$ ls sparks/Twiggy/
0.8.5
$
```

Then set up the directory structure for twig

```bsh
$ mkdir -p  application/themes/default/_layouts
```

And then,optionally,  you can update Twig to the latest version or version you want. The one in twiggy seems a little old :

```bsh
$ cd sparks/Twiggy/0.8.5/vendor/
$ rm -fr Twig/
$ git clone https://github.com/fabpot/Twig
```

The [twiggy link](http://edmundask.github.io/codeigniter-twiggy/) , has an example of templates you can use to test Twig.

Here's an example controller, `application/controllers/test.php`, using them and passing data as well (more on that [here](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/intro.html#installation):

```php
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Test extends CI_Controller {

    /* */
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->spark('Twiggy/0.8.5'); //enable Twig
    }

    public function index()
    {
        //set a data variable to pass, tell twiggy which template to use 
        //application/themes/default/index.html.twig, here

        $this->twiggy->set( 'data', array('name' => 'index') )->template('index')->display();
    }
}
```

Browsing to /test/index , you'll see the rendered result from your Twig template.

Answer (score 0):

There is a twig-codeigniter project with sources where you can find answers on your questions. Take a look at this page https://connect.sensiolabs.com/profile/bmatschullat/project/twig-codeigniter